# Utilizing Funcs within expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, func, ormlite-servicestack

### Background

I have an example of a test that passes but an error that happens down the pipeline and I'm not sure why. I'd like to figure out what's going on but I'm new to Expression construction and don't want to make any assumptions.

This is for a search filtering mechanism. It uses ServiceStack's `PredicateBuilder` implementation. I essentially have a list of values that I pass in, and I want it to construct an expression tree. I had previously done this just with `Func<T<bool>>` but realized that I needed to wind up with `Expression<Func<T<bool>>>`. Bummer.

### The Goal

Search filters built from Re-usable search filter types, which built out of `Func`s and `Expression`s that allows me to pass in a field name from an object along with values I should match on and wind up with something that we can run a `Where()` statement against.

### The Code / Issue

The generic "nullable bool" filter I'm trying -- sets up the acceptable items and returns a func that is meant to help filter:

```
public class NullableBoolFilter : IGenericSearchFilter<bool?>
{
    public Func<bool?, bool> GetFilterFunc(string valuesToProcess)
    {
        var acceptableValues = new List<bool?>();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valuesToProcess))
        {
            // all values acceptable
            acceptableValues = new List<bool?>{true, false, null};
        }
        else
        {
            if (!valuesToProcess.Contains("0") && !valuesToProcess.Contains("1"))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Nullable boolean filter attribute specified");
            }
            if (valuesToProcess.Contains("0"))
            {
                acceptableValues.Add(false);

            }
            if (valuesToProcess.Contains("1"))
            {
                acceptableValues.Add(true);
            }
        }

        Func<bool?, bool> returnFunc = delegate(bool? item) { return acceptableValues.Any(x=>x == item); };
        return returnFunc;
    }
}
```

Then I have another filter, which inherits from the `NullableBoolFilter` and attempts to use the Func:

```
public class ClaimsReportIsMDLFilter : NullableBoolFilter, ISearchFilter<vSEARCH_ClaimsReport>
{
    public Expression<Func<vSEARCH_ClaimsReport, bool>> GetExpression(string valuesToProcess)
    {
        var theFunc = base.GetFilterFunc(valuesToProcess);

        Expression<Func<vSEARCH_ClaimsReport, bool>> mdlMatches = item => theFunc(item.IsMDL);

        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<vSEARCH_ClaimsReport>();
        predicate = predicate.Or(mdlMatches);

        return predicate;

    }
}
```

The following test passes:

```
public class ClaimsReportIsMDLFilterTests
{
    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
    private readonly vSEARCH_ClaimsReport ItemWithMDL = new vSEARCH_ClaimsReport { IsMDL = true };
    private readonly vSEARCH_ClaimsReport ItemWithoutMDL = new vSEARCH_ClaimsReport { IsMDL = false };
    private readonly vSEARCH_ClaimsReport ItemWithNullMDL = new vSEARCH_ClaimsReport { IsMDL = null };
    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming

    [Fact]
    public void WithSearchValueOf1_HidesNonMDLAndNull()
    {

        var sut = this.GetCompiledExpressionForValues("1");

        sut.Invoke(ItemWithMDL).Should().BeTrue();
        sut.Invoke(ItemWithoutMDL).Should().BeFalse();
        sut.Invoke(ItemWithNullMDL).Should().BeFalse();

    }

    private Func<vSEARCH_ClaimsReport, bool> GetCompiledExpressionForValues(string searchValue)
    {
        return new ClaimsReportIsMDLFilter().GetExpression(searchValue).Compile();
    }

}
```

### The Problem

When I actually attempt to run this, I receive the error:

> variable 'param' of type 'vSEARCH_ClaimsReport' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

It makes sense to me why this might occur -- at the time it's evaluated, I don't have a real object to pass into the `Func`. However, I'm confused as to why my tests might pass but this doesn't in actual usage.

### Questions

- Why might my tests pass but I still receive this error?
- How the heck should I begin trying to fix this?
- Is there a remotely easy way to take that `Func` and turn it into an `Expression` that I can pass a field into?
- Do I need to abandon the generic filter idea and have each class manually add expressions to the `PredicateBuilder` based on input passed in? That's doable, but it seems like the work could be reduced more.

Comment: Your `NullableBoolFilter` appears to revolve around delegates, while your `ClaimsReportIsMDLFilter` revolves around expression trees. That's almost certainly the problem. If you want to use expression trees, you'll need to use them consistently - as soon as you've got an expression tree which refers to some local `Func<>`, nothing's going to be able to convert that into SQL (or whatever).

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the (quick!) response. This code currently is working: https://gist.github.com/SeanKilleen/0a8ffa639c4916af0585 given that, is there any way to create something that I could pass in a nullable bool field and have it be evaluated based on the same process every time? Or once I use expressions am I kind of stuck with that? I have several similar filters, so just looking to handle things uniformly and keep DRY as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why might my tests pass [...]

Because your test is simply compiling the expression down into the code that it represents and invoking it. It doesn't need to actually parse the expression tree and look at what the code it represents is doing, it just runs it and ensures that the output is right.

> Why might [...] I still receive this error?

Because when you're actually using it, it's not just executing the code; rather it is looking through the expression tree to try to determine what the code is doing *so that it can be translated into something else*, not so that it can be run as C# code.

Your expression is doing nothing but calling a delegate.  There is no way for someone traversing the expression tree to see inside the delegate and know what it's doing.  Knowing that you're calling another method isn't something that can be translated into another language.

> How the heck should I begin trying to fix this?

You need to generate an `Expression` from the start, rather than generating a `Func` and then just creating an `Expression` that calls it.

> Is there a remotely easy way to take that Func and turn it into an Expression that I can pass a field into?

No.  You'd need to pull out the IL code of the function, decompile that into C# code, then build up `Expression` objects to represent that code.  That's pretty much just not going to happen.

---

You're pretty much going to need to have `GetFilterFunc` return an `Expression`, to get this to work.  Fortunately, this is quite easy to do, given what you have.  You simply need to change the method signature and to replace the last two lines with the following:

```
return item => acceptableValues.Any(x => x == item);
```

And voila.  The lambda can be compiled into an `Expression` object, rather than a delegate, based on context, so if the return type of the method is an `Expression<Func<bool?,bool>>` that's what you'll get.

Now, to use this in `GetExpression`.  First off, the `PredicateBuilder` isn't really doing anything.  Adding an OR FALSE to your expression changes nothing meaningful about it.  All of that can go.  All that leaves us with is using an  `Expression<Func<bool?,bool>>` and changing it into an `Expression<Func<vSEARCH_ClaimsReport, bool>>` by pulling out a boolean property.  To do this is a bit more work for expressions than for delegates.  Rather than just invoking the expression, we need to do a tad more work to compose them.  We'll want to write a method to do this operation:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

And this relies on the use of the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}

internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

What this is doing is replacing all instances of the second expression's parameter with the body of the first expression, effectively inlining that expression into the second.  The rest is simply replacing all of the parameters with a new single parameter and wrapping it back up into a lambda.

Now that we have that, our method is quite easy:

```
public Expression<Func<vSEARCH_ClaimsReport, bool>> GetExpression(
    string valuesToProcess)
{
    Expression<Func<vSEARCH_ClaimsReport, bool?>> selector = 
        item => item.IsMDL;
    return selector.Compose(base.GetFilterFunc(valuesToProcess));
}
```

Comment: @Servy, can't thank you enough for this explanation. I think I still may be missing something though. In this gist I attempt to implement it: https://gist.github.com/SeanKilleen/1fa043025fed436eecc3 However, I'm receiving the same error. I kept the `PredicateBuilder` because we are doing `Or` searches inside of a larger `And` search and it's the way OrmLite expects it to come in AFAIK. Is that perhaps causing the problem? Thanks again for a great explanation; looking forward to understanding this better.

Comment: @SeanKilleen My guess would be that you have some sort of configuration issue to work through with your query provider, and I'm not familiar with the one that you mentioned.  The actual expression needed to be cleaned up, and this *should* generate something that the query provider can work with, but if there are any issues beyond building the correct `Expression` then that's not something I can help you with.

Comment: @Servy totally understandable, thanks! I just wanted to make sure that I hadn't screwed up the implementation somehow. I'll check it out further. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanKilleen have you tried using the .And and .Or methods provided by Ormlite?

Comment: @DanB we're actually generating our own expressions so that we can standardize them and use them across Ormlite's `PredicateBuilder` `And()` and `Or` methods. This lets us see which columns & values are coming in, automatically find all filters, and generate expressions that can be passed in to Ormlite. We create the individual or filters and then and them all together. I did get this working; will post my solution in a separate answer when I get a chance.